# Using cut command to display ping time

Tags: shell-script, ping

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=1.04 ms
```

Above I have a ping for my IP address how can I use the cut command or any other command to display
only the time in ms like this

```
time=1.04 ms
```

Comment: lets say I want something like this

Comment: Tue May 5 11:11:11 UTC 2020  time=0.838 ms how would I incorporated that

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `awk`:

```
$ ping localhost | awk '{ print $7, $8 }'

time=0.037 ms
time=0.113 ms
time=0.085 ms
time=0.070 ms
time=0.060 ms
time=0.055 ms
time=0.046 ms
time=0.072 ms
```

I'm using `awk` here to print the content of the 7th and 8th whitespace-delimited column. Notice that there's one blank line at the beginning; the line:

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
```

Doesn't have a 7th or 8th column.  If you ping has another column (e.g., `ttl`) you might need to adjust the column numbers from 7 and 8 to 8 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

With `cut`:

```
echo "64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=1.04 ms" | cut -d' ' -f7
time=1.04
```

from `ping`:

```
ping google.com | cut -d ' ' -f8

time=19.8
time=20.6
time=20.1
time=19.10
```